# Mysql | displaying data with 2 conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a table

[image]

i have to find the min and max prices and display the company name in a single table

Answer (score 0):

create new table and use foreign key in table or write select statement with joining condition*emphasized

Answer (score 0):

In SQL or any other table all the rows have same formulae , if you want to show min , max and company ; in this scenario there can be more than one companies , hence you have to write separate queries to show two separate table's row one with min and other with max .

You can write single query if you have one company by using `SELECT min(price) , max (price) .....` and you have to use group by for the query to work.

Comment: how can i combine there 2 queries into a single table ?

Answer (score 0):

If by company name you mean `bursa.name` column then do it with simple aggregation:

```
CREATE TABLE bursa_agg AS (
SELECT
    name
  , MIN(price) AS min_price
  , MAX(price) AS max_price
FROM bursa
GROUP BY name
);
```

If `bursa.companyid` is foreign key to some other table then use `JOIN` to get name for company from different table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE bursa_agg AS (
SELECT
    c.name -- column with company name
  , MIN(b.price) AS min_price
  , MAX(b.price) AS max_price
FROM bursa b
INNER JOIN company c ON -- name of company table
  b.companyid = c.companyid -- column with company id in company table
GROUP BY c.name
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(col2), MAX(col2) FROM table GROUP BY col1;
```